# Python translate large texts to English

Tags: python, nlp, translation, google-translate, language-translation

I am searching for a Python library that translates very large texts to English. I have already used `TextBlob` (which at some point just stops translating, API limits I suppose), `googletrans` (which at some point also just stops translating, it also doesn't translate very large texts and I have to split them into pieces and then merge). I am looking for a solution that I can be sure that it won't stop working, since I will be running this code regularly on around 100K texts with average word length of 10K. If anyone has done something similar, I would appreciate your help!

Comment: hmmm, is there other option?

Answer (score 3):

Python library *dl-translate* gets the job done very well. It is based on Huggingface transformers, with 2 available model options - mBART-50 Large (50 languages, personally I find it to be very accurate) and m2m100 (100 languages, but slightly less accurate). Link to github: https://github.com/xhluca/dl-translate

Comment: Since you have long tokens, you can use NLTK's sentence tokenizer to split by sentence before feeding it to the dl-translate (see [the section in the readme](https://github.com/xhluca/dl-translate#splitting-into-sentences))

Answer (score 1):

the Deepl API allows you to get 500k caracters every month, would this be enought?
https://www.deepl.com/en/docs-api/

might not be, but I wanted to be sure

Comment: Nope, because I have 100K texts of around 10K words. Say there are 20K texts with 10K words, this makes 200000000 words, which is much more than 500K characters.

Comment: 200M words, so around 1B char... yep not enought, let me look for more solutions

Comment: it is said that googletrans api is unlimited, are you sure it do not come from your code/ text ? a special char may break the translator?

Comment: This is also what I read, but for some reason it is not translating. If I take this example: https://py-googletrans.readthedocs.io/en/latest/, the translation is not working, the text is just as the original one.

Answer (score 1):

One can use mBART-50 ([paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2008.00401), [pre-trained model on Hugging Face](https://huggingface.co/facebook/mbart-large-50)). The pre-trained model on Hugging Face is under MIT license.

---

See below for an example code. Environment that I used on Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS with an NVIDIA A100 40GB GPU and CUDA 12.0:

```
conda create --name mbart-python39 python=3.9
conda activate mbart-python39 
pip install transformers==4.28.1
pip install chardet==5.1.0
pip install sentencepiece==0.1.99
pip install protobuf==3.20
```

Code (>95% of the code below is from from the [Hugging Face documentation](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/en/model_doc/mbart)):

```
from transformers import MBartForConditionalGeneration, MBart50TokenizerFast

article_fr = "Bonjour comment ca va?"
article_en = "What's going on?"

model = MBartForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("facebook/mbart-large-50-many-to-many-mmt")
tokenizer = MBart50TokenizerFast.from_pretrained("facebook/mbart-large-50-many-to-many-mmt")

# translate French to English
tokenizer.src_lang = "fr_XX"
encoded_fr = tokenizer(article_fr, return_tensors="pt")
generated_tokens = model.generate(**encoded_fr, forced_bos_token_id=tokenizer.lang_code_to_id["en_XX"])
translation =tokenizer.batch_decode(generated_tokens, skip_special_tokens=True)
print(translation)
# => "Hello, how are you?"

# translate English to French
tokenizer.src_lang = "en_XX"
encoded_en = tokenizer(article_en, return_tensors="pt")
generated_tokens = model.generate(**encoded_en, forced_bos_token_id=tokenizer.lang_code_to_id["fr_XX"])
translation = tokenizer.batch_decode(generated_tokens, skip_special_tokens=True)
print(translation)
# => "Qu'est-ce qui se passe?"
```

Comment: I also need to install torch, and update these libraries since with my torch version there was some incomprehensible error. To me it was better to use m2m100 since it was faster, as proposed by @sggg. See bottom of page https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/m2m_100 for equivalent code with m2m_100

Comment: @Learningfrommasters thanks good point, let's add it to the answer, which torch version did you eventually use?

Comment: from my pip freeze:

chardet==5.1.0
huggingface-hub==0.19.4
protobuf==3.20.0
requests==2.31.0
safetensors==0.4.1
sentencepiece==0.1.99
urllib3==2.1.0
sympy==1.12
tokenizers==0.15.0
torch==2.1.1
transformers==4.36.0